# Simplify $x! \le x(x-1)^{x-1}$ to $x! \le x^x.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The background of this problem is a proof by smallest counterexample. Can anyone point me in the right direction to continue simplification?

Comment: from this you get $(x-1)! \leq (x-1)^{x-1} $ does this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since $x$ is a positive integer and $x-1<x$, then:
$$x! \leq x(x-1)^{x-1}\leq x x^{x-1}=x^x$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$, $x(x-1)^{(x-1)} = x \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{x-1} x^{x-1} < x 1^{x-1} x^{x-1} = x^x$.